# Junit test Assertion Error expected 3 but came with 0

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, junit, geojson

I am working with microservices with Unit test. I have Dal services which is saving on database and another Account service supposed to be save on Dal service. When I test my code, it looks like my code working, which is: blue sign appeared but says my logic is not true. So in this sceneraio I am expecting to get size of 3 , however I am receiving size of 0

Any advice?

Thanks for answers

```java
    public class AccountEntity {

        @Id
        @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
        private Long id;

        @Column(nullable = false)
        private String Address;

        @Column(nullable = false)
        private String Password;

        @Column(nullable = false)
        private String authorizedPersonCode;

        @Column(nullable = false)
        private LocalDateTime creationDate;

        @Column(nullable = false)
        private boolean isActive;
```

```java
    private static final String SAVE_ACCOUNT_URL = "http://localhost:8443/api/v1/accounts";

        @Before
        public void AccountInit() {

            AccountModel AccountModel1 = AccountModel.builder()
                    .Address("f.k@account.com.tr").Password("Try2017")
                    .authorizedPersonCode("").creationDate(LocalDateTime.now()).isActive(true).build();


            HttpEntity<AccountModel> httpEntity1 = new HttpEntity<AccountModel>(AccountModel1);

            restTemplate.postForEntity(SAVE_ACCOUNT_URL, httpEntity1, AccountModel.class);


            AccountModel AccountModel2 = AccountModel.builder()
                    .Address("fk@tr").Password("2017")
                    .authorizedPersonCode("").creationDate(LocalDateTime.now()).isActive(false).build();

            HttpEntity<AccountModel> httpEntity2 = new HttpEntity<AccountModel>(AccountModel2);

            restTemplate.postForEntity(SAVE_ACCOUNT_URL, httpEntity2, AccountModel.class);


            AccountModel AccountModel3 = AccountModel.builder()
                    .Address("fu@..com.tr").Password("Ve7")
                    .authorizedPersonCode("").creationDate(LocalDateTime.now()).isActive(true).build();

            HttpEntity<AccountModel> httpEntity3 = new HttpEntity<AccountModel>(AccountModel3);

            restTemplate.postForEntity(SAVE_ACCOUNT_URL, httpEntity3, AccountModel.class);
        }

        @Test
        public void testGetAccountsFromDalSuccess() {

            PagedResources<AccountModel> resultAccounts = DelegatorService.getAccounts();

            Assert.assertEquals(3, resultAccounts.getContent().size());

        }
```

```java
public PagedResources<AccountModel> getAccounts() { 
    UriComponentsBuilder uriComponentsBuilder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(AccountDalURL);
    ResponseEntity<PagedResources<AccountModel>> accountModel = restTemplate.exchange(
                                  uriComponentsBuilder.build().toUri(), 
                                  HttpMethod.GET, 
                                  null, 
                                  new ParameterizedTypeReference<PagedResources<AccountModel>>() { }
                              ); 

    if (accountModel.getStatusCode().equals(HttpStatus.OK)) { 
        return accountModel.getBody(); 
    } else { 
        return null; 
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your unit test appears to be making a RESTful web service call.  This will likely fail because it is actually an integration test and requires a test harness so that the container (or whatever) can bootstrap and start your webservice (using SpringRunner for example if using Spring) and properly create/inject your restTemplate, etc.

If you're trying to do unit testing, you should not be relying on external services (databases, web services, filesystems, etc) for your tests.